# Problems after resuming from hibernate

Tags: 10.10, kernel, laptop

I have a problem with maverick when resuming from hibernate. Here's a screen shot:

(Image Error)

Also I'm getting the following errors before the screen appears:

```
*ERROR* render ring head not reset to zero ctl 00...

*ERROR* render ring head forced to zero ctl 00000...
```

I tried upgrading to PPA kernel to 2.5.36 and 2.5.37 beta but the problem persists. I have a vaio notebook with an Intel graphics card 4500mhd.

Anyone knows of a fix?

Comment: I don't really know if askubuntu should be a mean to do bugreports.

Comment: looks like a problem with the driver or the graphics card. You say it only happens on resume?

Comment: @Ronald Yes. I haven't yet tried suspend but I suspect that it does the same as hibernate.

Comment: As you tried 2.6.36/37 and this is Intel hardware graphics handling is via KMS in the kernel.  It is likely this is a card initialisation issue on resume.  You should file a bug on launchpad for this issue.  Use ubuntu-bug linux from the command line.

Comment: I'm about to ask a question here about troubles I'm having with standby/hibernate. Most of the time I can't even take a screenshot, the graphics problems are so bad.

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.